# CRC (8 bits?) brute force solving

Tags: crc, brute-force

I have 3 bytes set of data with a CRC code probably CRC-8 (the calculation might be with more bits and truncated) and I would like to find how it has been calculated. 
Is there any way to brute force the algorithm and the parameters? I tried it with [reveng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/) but it says "no model found".

Sample data (Hex):

```
1F 00 00
D7 01 00
F7 02 00
B5 03 00
E5 04 00
0E 05 00
23 06 00
8A 07 00
F0 08 00
2A 09 00
74 0A 00
05 0B 00
47 0C 00
D5 0D 00
8B 0E 00
51 0F 00
FF 10 00
37 11 00
17 12 00
55 13 00
05 14 00
EE 15 00
C3 16 00
6A 17 00
10 18 00
CA 19 00
94 1A 00
E5 1B 00
A7 1C 00
35 1D 00
6B 1E 00
B1 1F 00
F0 20 00
38 21 00
18 22 00
5A 23 00
0A 24 00
E1 25 00
CC 26 00
65 27 00
1F 28 00
C5 29 00
9B 2A 00
EA 2B 00
A8 2C 00
3A 2D 00
64 2E 00
BE 2F 00
F5 A1 00
D5 A2 00
97 A3 00
C7 A4 00
2C A5 00
01 A6 00
A8 A7 00
D2 A8 00
08 A9 00
56 AA 00
27 AB 00
65 AC 00
F7 AD 00
A9 AE 00
73 AF 00
32 90 00
FA 91 00
DA 92 00
98 93 00
C8 94 00
23 95 00
0E 96 00
A7 97 00
DD 98 00
07 99 00
59 9A 00
28 9B 00
6A 9C 00
F8 9D 00
A6 9E 00
7C 9F 00
0E 50 00
C6 51 00
E6 52 00
A4 53 00
F4 54 00
1F 55 00
32 56 00
9B 57 00
E1 58 00
3B 59 00
65 5A 00
14 5B 00
56 5C 00
C4 5D 00
9A 5E 00
40 5F 00
01 60 00
C9 61 00
E9 62 00
AB 63 00
FB 64 00
10 65 00
3D 66 00
94 67 00
EE 68 00
34 69 00
6A 6A 00
1B 6B 00
59 6C 00
CB 6D 00
95 6E 00
4F 6F 00
```

The first byte is the CRC, the two other bytes is the data.

And trying Reveng:

```
reveng -w 8 -s 00001f 0100d7 0200f7 0300b5 0400e5 05000e
```

gives me 'no model found'

Thanks

Comment: It's not a CRC. I can tell since it is not a linear function of the other bits.

Comment: Mark and @rcgldr, thank you for your comments! 

I thought that is was a bit more complicated than a CRC since Reveng didn't find the solution. 
Since it is not a CRC, do you know of a tool or method that I can use to find the algorithm? (I have more sample data that I can use to confirm the algo once found)

Comment: I updated my answer to note that there are two table entries with the same first byte:  01 A6 00 and 01 60 00

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Mark Adler, it's not a CRC. One way to check for this is to XOR two of the examples to see if you get a third example. Such as

```
F7 02 00 xor B5 03 00 = 42 01 00, which doesn't match D7 01 00
```

If the crc is post complemented, then 42 -> BD which still doesn't match D7.

---

Update - there are multiple entries with the same first byte, is this a mistake?

```
01 A6 00 and 01 60 00
0E 05 00 and 0E 50 00 and 0E 96 00
23 06 00 and 23 95 00
```

Comment: It is not a mistake, some share the same first byte.  But a given byte 2 and 3 will always give the same first byte.

Comment: @Alex - Are there always only 3 bytes? If so, you could make a 64K table rather than trying to figure out the algorithm.

Comment: yes, there is always 3bytes, but I don't know the first byte for all the possibilities... I could create a table with what I know, which is what I actually started doing, but I was wondering if someone ever came across a method or a brute force tool that I could use to 'hack' this algorithm?